# Making extra produced schunk globally invisible in Sweave

Tags: sweave, r

I'm using `ASREML-R` for data analysis. When I fit the model in `ASREML-R`, it produces some information regarding the model like this

```
dat <- data.frame(y=rnorm(20),x=seq(1,20))
ex.asr <- asreml(y ~ x, data=dat)


asreml(): 3.0.1 Library: 3.01gl IA32  Run: Wed Jan 11 16:53:31 2012

     LogLik         S2      DF
    -13.3387      0.9556    18  16:53:31
    -13.3387      0.9556    18  16:53:31

Finished on: Wed Jan 11 16:53:31 2012

LogLikelihood Converged
```

and even using `<<echo=FALSE>>=` in `Sweave` produces this extra `Schunk`

```
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Soutput}

asreml(): 3.0.1 Library: 3.01gl IA32  Run: Wed Jan 11 16:53:31 2012

     LogLik         S2      DF
    -13.3387      0.9556    18  16:53:31
    -13.3387      0.9556    18  16:53:31

Finished on: Wed Jan 11 16:53:31 2012

LogLikelihood Converged 

\end{Soutput}
\end{Schunk}
```

I wonder how can I remove this extra information to display in my final output.

Comment: Can't you just put `<<echo=FALSE>>=` before the code chunk in your `.Rnw` file?

Comment: Thanks @Alan for your comment and suggestion. But this does not work in this case. Anyhow thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo=FALSE` suppresses printing of the input. To hide the output, you need to add `results=hide`:

```
<<...,echo=FALSE,results=hide>>=

  # Your code here

@
```

Comment: Duh.  I don't know what I was thinking with my comment. That's what I meant to write.

Comment: (+1) @Sharpie: Thanks a lot. This works fine. Thanks again.

Comment: @AlanMunn: No worries, I get `echo` and `results` mixed up all the time when I haven't written any Sweave in a while.